# Do late night shows inform celebrities who their co-guests are going to be so they can agree to appear on the show with them?

Tags: talk-shows, late-show-stephen-colbert, david-letterman-show, jimmy-kimmel-live

I got thinking about this ever since I saw an old Letterman video featuring Howard Stern, in which Howard gave an account of how he had a conflict with Sharon Stone the last time he was on the show. She was the other guest.

Do these shows have to get the guests acceptance as to their co-guest so as to avoid any possible conflict in case they don't like the other person?

Comment: Sometimes yes, sometimes no.